# upgrade jupyter notebooks from julia 0.4 etc to 0.6

Tags: julia, upgrade, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

New releases of julia are backward compatible with old. I have a bunch of Jupyter exercises in development version of Julia 0.4, 0.5 - Coursera et al

Is there an easy way to open Notebooks in the latest version for installed language, or an app to covert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Menu item: Kernel, change kernel